# How to zoom in on a polygon in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to figure out how to do the same zooming behavior as shown in the example below, but with a normal polygon instead of the geo paths.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541

I have seen some answers here on SO that kind of address this, but the animation is choppy or jumps around strangely.

The html I have is

```
<div id="map-container">
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     id="canvas"
     viewBox="0 0 4328 2880">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="mapPattern"
                 patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                 x="0"
                 y="0"
                 width="4328"
                 height="2880">
            <image xlink:href="/development/data/masterplan.png"
                   x="0"
                   y="0"
                   width="4328"
                   height="2880"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g id="masterGroup">
        <rect fill="url(#mapPattern)"
              x="0"
              y="0"
              width="4328"
              height="2880" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to be able to add some polygons in the same group as the map rectangle and then zoom on the polygon's boundary. Can anyone please show me a fiddle of such behaviour?

I should also add that I do not want to use the scroll wheel or panning. Just zooming in on a clicked polygon and then zooming out on another click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you. I answered a question here earlier today : [D3js outer limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340215/d3js-outer-limits/37343252#37343252)

Here is the fiddle I put together : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/JnNwu/921/

I have added a transition : `svg.transition().duration(1000).attr('transform',function(d){`

Notice if you click one of the nodes the area moves to cater for the size of the new layout.

The basics are explained in the link to the question, but basically I got the bounding box and translated the SVG accordingly. So I translated and scaled to the size of the new rectangle.

Take a look, quite easy to understand. Here is the main part of the transition :

```
svg.transition().duration(1000).attr('transform',function(d){

var testScale = Math.max(rectAttr[0].width,rectAttr[0].height)
var widthScale = width/testScale
var heightScale = height/testScale 
var scale = Math.max(widthScale,heightScale);

var transX = -(parseInt(d3.select('#invisRect').attr("x")) + parseInt(d3.select('#invisRect').attr("width"))/2) *scale + width/2;
var transY = -(parseInt(d3.select('#invisRect').attr("y")) + parseInt(d3.select('#invisRect').attr("height"))/2) *scale + height/2;

return 'translate(' + transX + ','+ transY + ')scale('+scale+')' ;
})
```

So with your code, your `rectAttr` values as seen in the snippet above would be the values retrieved from the getBoundingClientRect() of your polygon : `x, y, width and height`.

Where I have used `d3.select('#invisRect')`, this should be your boundingBoxRect() also. And the rest should just work.

EDIT

Here are the edits I made with the fiddle provided : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/nzt39dym/3/

I used this function to get the bounding box of the polygon and set the rectangles values accordingly :

```
var bbox = d3.select(polygon).node().getBBox();

var rectAttr = {
    x: bbox.x,
    y: bbox.y,
    width: bbox.width,
    height: bbox.height,
  };
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out where exactly to place the transition and how to get the correct data, etc. I've created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nzt39dym/1/  Would it be too much to ask of you to please show me how to accomplish that in there?

Comment: What is it youre trying to do ? Zoom in to the polygons on click and zoom out onclick ?

Comment: Yes. Basically as the first link shows, instead of zooming in on states, I'd like to zoom in on either of the two polygons and then be able to zoom completely back out on click.

Comment: I have added to the answer. The zoom isn't perfect at all, but it will get you started :) Hope that helps

Comment: Absolutely awesome. It's a start and I can at least finally see how it comes together. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem :)) Glad i could help

Comment: The calculation of scale above allows the bounds of the rect to expand past its container. If you use `const scale = Math.min(widthScale, heightScale)` it will be constrained and you won't lose any part of your zoomed polygon.